# Rails: submit a form with more than one row of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails project and it is kind like the example in 'Railstutorial' [Fig 7.11](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#fig-signup_mockup)

Mine is a little bit different. I want the user can create more than one account at a time which means, i will have an extra button 'add' in order to stack up all the information.

For instance, after filling out all the four textareas, you hit add, and you will stay in this page with the information showed up in a box, you can keep creating another account. And when you click on the 'create my account' button, all the data will be inserted into the database together while the page will be directed to some other url(I can do this part).

But what I can do right now is only creating one account at one time.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), which lets you add fields dynamically.